# What is the best method for ripping DVD to stream to Xbox 360?

Tags: dvd, windows-media-center, encoding, ripping, xbox360

What is the best method to rip/encode a standard definition DVD, to be streamed to a Xbox360 from a Vista Media Center pc (preferably using free software).   I’ve found tons of tutorials on the web  explaining how to create wmv’s from vob files using FFMpeg, but every combination of settings that I have tried has resulted in very poor video quality.  I’ve also tried various video conversion tools, but everything seems to result in poor video quality, or audio that is out of sync with the picture.  Please help!

Comment: Cant you just put the DVD in the Xbox, you know, with the DVD drive?

Comment: Yes, the xbox will play dvd's from the drive, but I want to stream them from my pc, so I don't have to fumble with discs to change movies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on-the-fly transcoding by stuff like tversity?

http://tversity.com/download/